# Ubuntu 20.04 userspace boot time slow

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04

i have a thinkpad t470 with a 512gb ssd in dual boot with windows and since a couple of days its been slow to boot, what could be the problem?

```
❯ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 6.112s (firmware) + 7.896s (loader) + 2.188s (kernel) + 32.111s (userspace) = 48.309s 
graphical.target reached after 32.060s in userspace

❯ systemd-analyze blame
28.501s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
 2.612s fwupd-refresh.service                                
 1.833s dev-loop11.device                                    
 1.831s dev-loop12.device                                    
 1.827s dev-loop9.device                                     
 1.827s dev-loop13.device                                    
 1.710s dev-loop8.device                                     
 1.667s dev-loop15.device                                    
 1.654s dev-loop10.device                                    
 1.611s ua-timer.service                                     
 1.583s dev-loop14.device                                    
 1.547s dev-loop16.device                                    
 1.506s dev-nvme0n1p5.device                                 
 1.446s dev-loop7.device                                     
 1.260s fwupd.service                                        
  982ms systemd-rfkill.service                               
  819ms apport.service                                       
  689ms accounts-daemon.service                              
  653ms avahi-daemon.service                                 
  595ms snapd.service                                        
  539ms NetworkManager.service                               
  475ms systemd-logind.service                               
  472ms apport-autoreport.service                            
  438ms networkd-dispatcher.service                          
  372ms dev-loop2.device                                     
  368ms dev-loop1.device                                     
  365ms dev-loop3.device                                     
  363ms dev-loop0.device                                     
  361ms systemd-resolved.service                             
  356ms udisks2.service                                      
  344ms e2scrub_reap.service                                 
  326ms snapd.apparmor.service                               
  321ms dev-loop6.device                                     
  319ms gpu-manager.service                                  
  305ms grub-common.service                                  
  301ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
  290ms systemd-journal-flush.service                        
  280ms snap-bare-5.mount                                    
  268ms snap-core20-1695.mount                               
  264ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-161.mount              
  262ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-115.mount              
  260ms apparmor.service                                     
  259ms dev-loop4.device                                     
  257ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-119.mount              
  249ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-29.mount                    
  248ms polkit.service                                       
  247ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount              
  247ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
  243ms snap-postman-184.mount                               
  241ms snap-snap\x2dstore-558.mount                         
  241ms dev-loop5.device                                     
  240ms snap-snap\x2dstore-599.mount                         
  238ms snap-snapd-16292.mount                               
  237ms snap-snapd-17336.mount                               
lines 1-54
```

Comment: You can look at `systemd-analyze blame` also. Please [edit] your question and add the extra information. Do not comment.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a few applications installed as snaps, and loop devices are mounted for each of them:

```
1.833s dev-loop11.device
1.831s dev-loop12.device
1.827s dev-loop9.device
1.827s dev-loop13.device
1.710s dev-loop8.device
1.667s dev-loop15.device
1.654s dev-loop10.device
```

You can uninstall the snaps that you don't use.

Comment: nice how i can do that?

Comment: To list all installed snap applications, simply run `snap list` in terminal.  

To remove an app, run `snap remove vlc`.

Comment: can i edit the post and show you what i have install so you can tell me what i can delete?